# Autoplay a video within slick slider

Tags: html, jquery, video, slick.js, autoplay

I'm using slick slider downloaded from http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I have a number of images on autoplay displaying correctly, however, i also have an mp4 file that i cant get to autoplay. Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="regular slider" style="width: 900px; left: 60px; top: 230px;">
    <div>        
        <video autoplay>
            <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
 </section>
```

And here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 2000
      });
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: It seems that the autoplay works to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slick.js and html5 video autoplay and pause on video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521763/slick-js-and-html5-video-autoplay-and-pause-on-video)

Answer (score 1):

Video needs to be muted for autoplay to work.

```
<video autoplay muted>
     <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I quote @AsafDavid. Look at the working code example in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31523229/6263942).**

> Yes it can be done using JavaScript. When the video slide becomes the
>   `currentSlide` you have to:
>
> 1. pause the slider
> 2. play the video
>
> You can do this using the `afterChange` event:
>
> ```
> $('.sliderMain').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){ 
>   if (currentSlide == 5) { 
>     $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPause'); myVideo.play(); 
>   } 
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **afterChange** Callback function to achieve this.

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $('#video')[0].play(); 
});
```