# Slick Carousel autoplay video slide1

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have a slick carousel, within the first slide I am autoplaying a video. This is working when the slick starts, shows the 2nd slide then gets back to the 1st. But I cannot get this to work on `pageload`, I think this is because I am using `afterChange`. You can see my example [here](https://www.ec-projects.co.uk/element/)

The JavaScript for firing is:

```
$('.top-carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000,
    dots: true,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
});

  $('.top-carousel').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    if ($("#slick-slide00").hasClass("slick-active")) {
      $('.top-carousel').slick('slickPause');
      theVideo.play();
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('theVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

  function myHandler(e) {
    $('.top-carousel').slick('slickPlay');
  }
```

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: can you call inside of document ready function 'theVideo.play();'

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { theVideo.play();});

Comment: Have you tried adding the `init` event? `$('.top-carousel').on('afterChange init'`

Comment: Some possibilities here, most to do with reloading the video iframe when the slide is visible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349155/slick-slider-pause-youtube-video-when-slide-change

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it with my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68877957/888462